# 'This user account is blocked. Contact registration@vercel.com'

Tags: github, deployment, next.js, vercel

#### Clicking 'Continue with GitHub' fails

I am attending the Udemy course
[React - The Complete Guide (incl Hooks, React Router, Redux)](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/)
I have followed the instructions given there.

Video number 347 (at 9:14) instructs me to go to
https://vercel.com/signup and then click *Continue with GitHub*,
which I did – several times.

But I always get the same message:
*This user account is blocked. Contact registration@vercel.com for
more information.*

[image: This user account is blocked. Contact registration@vercel.com for more information.]

#### My question(s)

*Why did this happen? – How do I get unblocked and proceed?*
*My ultimate goal is to automatically deploy the NextJS project at
https://vercel.com via GitHub.*

#### Clicking 'Continue with Email →' succeeds

After sending a few emails back and forth trying to get support, I
didn't feel much wiser, but I decided to click on *Login* in the
top-right corner, and then on *Continue with Email →*.

[image: This user account is blocked. Contact registration@vercel.com for more information.]

After confirming my email address, I got a message saying
**Sign Up Successful** but then nothing more happened.
So I did it once more, and this time I automatically got redirected to
the Vercel dashboard, https://vercel.com/dashboard.

Getting to the dashboard feels like a step forward, but I still don't
know how to proceed.
<sup>1</sup>

[image: The Vercel dashboard.]

#### References

- [React - The Complete Guide (incl Hooks, React Router, Redux)](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/)
- https://vercel.com/login/email

---

1
Going back and clicking 'Continue with GitHub' still displays the
 same old message:

*This user account is blocked. Contact registration@vercel.com for
more information.*

Comment: Try reading https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/33365 to see if any of those comments/posts help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why did this happen? – How do I get unblocked and proceed?*
> *My ultimate goal is to automatically deploy the NextJS project at
> https://vercel.com via GitHub.*

Since you managed to get unblocked, I will focus on building and
deploying the project at https://vercel.com.
Below I describe what worked for me.

##### 1. Install the Vercel app at GitHub

I went to https://github.com/apps/vercel and clicked *Install*.

[image: Install the Vercel app at GitHub, step 1.]

Doing so took me to a
https://github.com/apps/vercel/installations/new/permissions link.

Here too, I clicked the *Install* button – located in the lower-left
part of the page.
<sup>1</sup>

[image: Install the Vercel app at GitHub, step 2.]

##### 2. In the Vercel dashboard, get the project's code from GitHub

I was then redirected to a page at https://vercel.com/ saying
**Installation Approved**.

[image: Vercel: installation approved.]

Here I clicked *Go to Dashboard* which took me to the Vercel
dashboard, https://vercel.com/dashboard – as shown in the last image
of your question.

In the dashboard, I clicked *Create a New Project* which took me to
https://vercel.com/new, with the headline
**Let's build something new**.

[image: The Vercel 'Let's build something new' page.]

The top-most git repository, `nextjs-meetups-demo`, is the site I
wanted to deploy.
So I clicked its *Import* button.

##### 3. Configure and deploy the project

I was now taken to a https://vercel.com/new/import page with the
headline **Configure Project**.
Since I was happy with all the default settings, I simply clicked
*Deploy*.

[image: Configure the Vercel project.]

After building for 51 seconds, I was congratulated for having deployed
my NextJS site.
Clicking the image redirected me to the *React Meetups* site, finally
proving it was deployed.
<sup>2</sup>

[image: Congratulations upon deploying the project at Vercel.]

#### References

- [Install the Vercel app at GitHub](https://github.com/apps/vercel)
- [The Vercel 'build something new' page](https://vercel.com/new)

---

1
This apparently gives Vercel access to my repositories at GitHub so
 that it can build and deploy any of my projects.

2
Unfortunately, my site at Vercel does not display any newly added
meetups – even though I can see in MongoDB that a meetup has been
created.
This would call for a whole new Stack Overflow question, so I won't
delve into it here.